# JToken jsonbody pass within a class

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, httpresponsemessage

I'm trying to build a web api and received the whole body in one raw json parameter (jsonbody). I won't to pass it as JToken item class

This work:

```
   [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage WebRequestTest2([FromBody]JToken jsonbody)
    {...}
```

This not work (Inputs is null):

```
public class mdWREvent {public JToken jsonbody { get; set; }}
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage WebRequestTest1([FromBody] mdWREvent Inputs)
    {...}
```

How can I make this to work also?

Answer (score 0):

In the first scenario it will try to deserialize the whole body as json, in the second scenario it will try to deserialize the body as "Inputs" and the property "jsoninputs" as a Json Object.

For example,
Json for Scenario 1:

```
{
    "prop1" : 1,
    "prop2": "value"
}
```

Json for Scenario 2:

```
{
    "jsoninputs": {
        "prop1" : 1,
        "prop2": "value"
    }
}
```

PS: You don't have to mark it with [FromBody] if it's a object for a POST/PUT.

Comment: In the first scenario I get jsonbody={"a": "b"}. This is the required result in the second scenario. Currently I get Inputs.jsonbody = null in the second one.

Comment: Can you describe your request?